# Can we send authorization token in body in postman

Tags: android, laravel, api, authorization, postman

I am making a video upload API.The android developer asked for the authorization token to be send in the body whereas I was sending it as a bearer token and also I added in the header (authorization). But I am confused that how to send it in the body and is it valid approach??

Comment: You can send token in header, body or inquery params. But, GET/HEAD/DELETE methods may not work as expected if it is sent via body. 

Refer:

[Link][1]

  [1]: https://community.apigee.com/questions/28794/best-practices-for-passing-an-access-token-without.html

Comment: how  to send it in body

Answer (score 0):

depending on your web server the full URL might get logged in its log files. Depending on how sensitive the data is you might not want your IT people having access to all the tokens.

Additionally the URL with the query string would be saved in your user's history, allowing other users of the same machine to access the URL.

Finally and what makes this very insecure is, the URL is sent in the Referer header of all requests for any resource, even third party resources. So if your using Google Analytics for example, you will send Google the URL token in and all to them.

In my opinion this is a bad idea of sending token in body.

Ask your android developer to send the access token in header.

Comment: I just wan to try with it.could you please help me how to send it in body? if I send a parameter in body as token and keep it outside of middleware then makes no sense.

Comment: @anonymous i am quite not getting you, However if you don't want to send the token in header then simply send it as a string in "Key-Value" pair in your request.